# Does push-ups on finger tips affect eyesight negatively?

Tags: alternative-medicine, ophthalmology, physical-fitness

Some time ago I've been told that push-ups on your fingers (instead on fists) can affect eye-sight. The explanation was not clear (something about a lot of nerves in fingertips and pressure on them).

> According to some teachers of Chinese systems, the fingertips should not be trained at all, as in Chinese medicine over-stimulation of the fingertips can affect one's eyesight.

[Blade forum - thread about doing push-ups on fingertips](http://www.bladeforums.com/forums/showthread.php/95614-Push-ups-on-your-fingertips-Can-they-damage-you)

> Doing push-ups on tips of fingers stresses and damages meridian pathways (this is oriental medicine) and may damage health and generally speaking,eyes.

[Martial Talk - thread about finger push-ups](http://www.martialtalk.com/forum/showthread.php?3455-finger-pushups-and-knife-hand)

Is it at least partly true ?

Comment: Why the martial arts tag?

Comment: @nico, the claim is common in martial arts, where people do a lot of push ups and are exposed to chinese medicine. In fact, both links above are from martial arts forums.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.myspace.com/glenducharme/photos/12326397#{%22ImageId%22%3A12326397}), I should've seen way more monks wearing glasses. Then again, glasses are for the weak. ;)

Comment: @Sklivvz The question is unrelated to martial arts though. Unrelated to Sklivvz; the question contains references to forum, forum posts have bigger chance to disappear, if the forum die, or someone delete the post or anything. Links are more in risk zone for link rot.

Comment: The [tag:exercise] does seem to fit better than [tag:martial-arts] since I've heard that over-straining in general (i.e. not just finger pushups) can also cause problems with eyesight.

Comment: I did remove the martial arts tag.